# Javascript CountDown showing NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have been working on my own costum Javascript Countdown for multiple countdowns at the site.

But i am facing problems. The date doesn't count correctly.

It works perfectly in Google Chrome, but in Firefox it just says NaN.

Can someone tell me what's wrong with me code?

```
function countdown(date, span){
    today = new Date();

    BigDay = new Date(date);
    msPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ;
    timeLeft = (BigDay.getTime() - today.getTime());
    e_daysLeft = timeLeft / msPerDay;
    daysLeft = Math.floor(e_daysLeft);
    e_hrsLeft = (e_daysLeft - daysLeft)*24;
    hrsLeft = Math.floor(e_hrsLeft);
    minsLeft = Math.floor((e_hrsLeft - hrsLeft)*60);
    secLeft = Math.floor( 60 - today.getSeconds() );

    $("#"+span).html("<ul class='dayTime'><li><small>" + daysLeft + "</small><span>Dage</span></li><li><small>" + hrsLeft +"</small><span>Timer</span></li><li><small>" + minsLeft + "</small><span>Min</span></li><li><small>" + secLeft + "</small><span>Sek</span></li></ul>");
 }
```

I am running the code like

```
  countdown("2013-05-30 00:00:00", "container");
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem with your code is the **date format**. Please change it to:

```
countdown("2013/05/30 00:00:00", "container");
```

The above format works almost in all the browsers. For more information, please refer these links:

- [Simplified](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html)
- [Javascript Date.parse browser compatibility issue](http://craiccomputing.blogspot.in/2010/11/javascript-dateparse-browser.html)